# Charts MarkerView in MacOS won't display

Tags: macos, nsview, ios-charts

This question is in reference to [DanielGindi/Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) but I think some knowledge of `NSView` rendering might help even if you're not familiar with the `Charts` library.

I'm using `Charts` in a MacOS project, and having trouble with getting `MarkerView` to display correctly. I've copied `RadarMarkerView` from the ChartsDemo-iOS project to ChartsDemo-macOS in order to use it in the MacOS `RadarDemoViewController`. But the marker never appears in the view when I click on a value in the chart.

Here is the full implementation of `RadarMarkerViewMac`:

```
public class RadarMarkerViewMac: MarkerView {
  @IBOutlet var label: NSTextField!

  public override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.offset.x = -self.frame.size.width / 2.0
    self.offset.y = -self.frame.size.height - 7.0
  }

  public override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    label.stringValue = String.init(format: "%.3f %%", (entry.y))
    _ = self // see note 2
    layout() // see note 1
  }
}
```

As you can see if you look at the original [RadarMarkerView](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/ChartsDemo-iOS/Swift/Components/RadarMarkerView.swift), there are only two notable changes:

1. `layoutIfNeeded()` is changed to `layout()` because the former function doesn't exist in `NSView`.
2. I put this line in there so that I could add a breakpoint to see if `self` was being drawn correctly (when paused for a breakpoint, hover mouse over `self`, then click the eyeball button to see the view).

The weird thing I discovered was this: Clicking on the chart highlights the selected value but doesn't show the marker. However, when I put a breakpoint on the `layout()` line, then viewed `self` with the preview popup, I saw the view just fine... and then once I continued the app running, the marker appeared as it should in the chart in all subsequent selections, even with the breakpoint disabled.

Also important to note, I think, is that if I put the breakpoint in and DIDN'T show the preview, the marker would not display on the chart.

I assume this has something to do with the `NSView` rendering, but I haven't been able to make the app behave correctly here. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not sufficient to only copy `RadarMarkerView`.

You need to create a corresponding xib for macOS. In `RadarDemoViewController` in `viewDidLoad` load the view from xib and add it as a subview outside of visible area, so that it can be rendered:

```
let marker = RadarMarkerView.viewFromXib()!
marker.chartView = radarChartView
radarChartView.marker = marker

self.view.addSubview(marker)
marker.frame = NSRect(x: -100, y: -100, width: 64, height: 64)
```

As one can see in MarkerView a property `nsuiLayer` is used, which basically corresponds to `self.layer`.

Therefore you need to specify that you want the view to use a layer as its backing store.

```
public required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: decoder)
    wantsLayer = true
}
```

You can define an offset (depending on the size of your view):

```
open override func offsetForDrawing(atPoint point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: -36, y: -40)
}
```

And in `refreshContent` you specify that the view needs a layout pass before it can be drawn with

```
needsLayout = true
```

So the complete `RadarMarkerView` looks something like this:

```
import AppKit
import Charts

public class RadarMarkerView: MarkerView {
    @IBOutlet var label: NSTextField!

    public required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        wantsLayer = true
    }

    open override func draw(context: CGContext, point: CGPoint) {
//        NSColor.red.setFill()
//        NSRect(x: point.x - 32, y: point.y - 32, width: 64, height: 64).fill()
        super.draw(context: context, point: point)
    }

    open override func offsetForDrawing(atPoint point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: -36, y: -40)
    }


    public override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
        label.stringValue = String.init(format: "%d %%", Int(round(entry.y)))
        needsLayout = true
    }
}
```

Note the override of `draw(context:point:)`. To make debugging easier, you can programmatically draw a red rectangle (just uncomment the two lines).

**Test**

[image: marker test]

As you can see the marker is then shown.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for that. I had already made the xib, but it was adding the marker view to the chartview and adding wantsLayer that did the trick.